# error when running streamline as frontend and FastAPI as backend

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, streamlit

I have developed a machine learning app with fastapi as the backend, and streamlit as the frontend, it works on my local machine when I run it, i am abe to generate th predictions using the streamlit running on fastapi backend. But using docker , individually they work, I can generate predictions using fast API, and I can view the UI using streamlit, but if I want to generate the predictions on the streamlit UI, it generates this error:

`ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with URL: /predict (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffa808a0d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Where could the error be coming from?

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Docker compose, the services declared in the Docker compose file will be in the same network.

Reference them inside your Python code using the service name as defined in the Docker compose file. For example:

### Docker compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
    - 2000:2000

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
    - 8000:8501
```

### Streamlit code

```
import requests
import streamlit as st

BASE_URL = "http://backend:2000/"  # Works with Docker compose

if st.button("Give me the version number!"):
    url_suffix = "version_number"
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL + url_suffix)
    with st.spinner("Requesting version number"):
        st.write(response.json())
```

Note how from the Streamlit app a request will be sent to the FastAPI backend using url: `http://backend:2000/version_number`. The `backend` and the `2000` should match up with the Docker compose file.

See also: [Docker Compose - container receiving connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781805/docker-compose-container-receiving-connection-refused)